# selenium script in python and I face an error says"Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, whatsapp

`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import os

## Replace with the path to your chromedriver executable

chromedriver_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'chromedriver_win32', 'chromedriver.exe')

## Replace with the path to the files you want to send

files_to_send = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'files', 'In action presentation.pdf'),
os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'files', 'WhatsApp Audio 2023-03-08 at 12.15.51 AM.ogg')]

## Replace with your message text

message = "Hello, this is a test message."

## List of phone numbers

phone_numbers = ['+1234567890']

## Initialize the Chrome webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)

## Open WhatsApp Web

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

## Wait for the user to scan the QR code

input('Scan the QR code and press Enter to continue...')

## Loop through the list of phone numbers

for phone_number in phone_numbers:

```
# Navigate to the chat with the phone number
driver.get(f'https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={phone_number}')

try:
    # Wait for the chat window to load
    chat_window = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="_3uMse"]')
    time.sleep(5)

    # Click on the attachment button
    attachment_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@title="Attach"]')
    attachment_button.click()

    # Click on the "Document" option
    document_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@accept="*"]')
    document_button.send_keys('\n'.join(files_to_send))

    # Wait for the files to upload
    time.sleep(10)

    # Type the message text
    message_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "input")]')
    message_box.send_keys(message)

    # Send the message
    send_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-icon="send"]')
    send_button.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print(f'Unable to send message to {phone_number}. Chat window not found.')
```

## Close the webdriver

driver.quit()
`

when i run the code whatsapp web open then I scan the code but then nothing else happens
and the terminal give me this :
[the output from the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XveUn.png)
I want this script to send some files and a text message to list of numbers in whatsapp web
and I just face this error but I cant find any syntax error or logical , I dont understand what is wrong with the usb port , I tried to plug in a USB it it works just fine , unfortunate I dont have another device to try the script on I hope some one can help me with this
and thanks in advance , your fellow beginner new learner programmer :)